# Чтение JSON из файла используя GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Пытаюсь банально прочитать json файл, с последующим созданием объекта класса, но ничего не выходит,BufferedReader даже не читает файл, хотя в примерах он напрямую передается в GSON, зависимость в pom файл добавил..

Сам json такого формата

```
{
  "student": [{
    "name": "Ivan",
    "surname": "Ivanov",
    }, {
     
     "name": "Peter",
    "surname": "Ivanov",
  }]
}
```

Создал два класса

```
public class POJOStudents
{
     String name;
     String surname;
    
}
```

И

```
public class GeneralStudents {
    List<POJOStudents> general;

}
```

Класс main

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
    
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\students.json"));
            GeneralStudents students = gson.fromJson(br, GeneralStudents.class);
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас json некорректный, уберите запятые после `"surname": "Ivanov",`

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильное имя переменной в основном классе:

```
public class GeneralStudents {
    List<POJOStudents> general;

}
```

Должно быть вместо `student` вместо `general`

Comment: Поправил, но все равно ошибка

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)

Comment: Если передать в GSON строку на прямую, то все работает, судя по всему BufferedReader некорректно читает файл.

Comment: Попробуйте вот так файл считать: `JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));`

Comment: не получается, пробовал просто прочитать файл и вывести строку, выводит всего пару непонятных символов п»ї{,

Comment: Возможно, дело в кодировке файла. Посмотрите, не отличается ли она от `UTF-8`

Comment: Вообщем считывал этот символ п»ї .Это в начале файла специальная последовательность байт, указывающую, что файл в кодировке UTF-8, прочитал все в строку, поменял на массив GeneralStudents [ ]students = gson.fromJson(br, GeneralStudents [ ].class) , но обьект класса так и не создается.

Comment: У вас не массив. Уберите квадратные скобки